# Sort by date, group by name Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nssortdescriptor

Currently I have an application with core data that has a view controller which requires a specific sorting for the UITableView. An entity can have a `event_name` and `assigned_time`, along with other attributes. The basic idea is if an event is assigned to a more recent time, then that event will be shown first in the tableview.

What I want to know is what is the best way of sorting my information by `assigned_time` but group by `event_name`? I have tried using `NSSortDescriptor` with the section being `assigned_time` but I then just end up ordering by the name and not having the event with earlier times come first in the list.

Essentially I want to achieve something similar to how email threads work where entities with a more recent `assigned_time` coming in will push a section up the list hence why the section ordering depends on the time

My code for the NSFetchRequest is as follows:

```
func getFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {
      let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "EntitySet")
      request.predicate = ...
      let eventSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "event_name", ascending: true)
      let timeSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "assigned_time", ascending: false)
      request.sortDescriptors = [eventSort, timeSort]
      return request
}
```

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried? You'll get more and better answers If you show what you've tried, and demonstrate that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself. See [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var request : NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>!
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "event_name", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "assigned_time", ascending: true)]
request.propertiesToGroupBy = ["event_name"]
```

Comment: Don't I need to specify an ordering on `event_name` if thats my section?

Comment: you said you want to order by assigned_time and then group by event_name ?

Comment: Yeah so `event_name` will be my tableview section headers. I might be mistaken but I read somewhere you have to specify a sort order for your sections?

Comment: I updated the code. Your primary order field is event_name then, and secondary date

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work still... The problem is the order of the sections depends on the `assigned_time` of the objects inside each section